# count the tuples of a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, count, tuples

I have the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
      val1 val2 val3 val4
1      7    8    3    2
2      1    4    5    4
3      5    7    5    3
4      7    8    3    2
5      6    8    1    0
6      0    2    5    7
7      1    4    5    4
8      7    8    3    2
```

And I would like to count the number of each tuples in my DataFrame. Expected results (more or less):

```
count     tuple
3         (7, 8, 3, 2)
2         (1, 4, 5, 4)
1         (5, 7, 5, 3)
1         (6, 8, 1, 0)
1         (0, 2, 5, 7)
```

Note also that my true DataFrame has **millions of entries**, so I do need some solution which is time-optimized.

Untill now, my way was to convert each column in a string column with `Series.astype(str)`, and then concatenate the columns, and use a `pandas.Series.value_counts()`. But I think there might be a faster and more natural method to solve my problem. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the natural solution would be to use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
>>> res = df.groupby(list(df.columns)).size()
>>> res
val1  val2  val3  val4
0     2     5     7       1
1     4     5     4       2
5     7     5     3       1
6     8     1     0       1
7     8     3     2       3
dtype: int64
>>> res.index = [tuple(x) for x in res.index]
>>> res = res.reset_index().set_index(0)
>>> res
          index
0              
1  (0, 2, 5, 7)
2  (1, 4, 5, 4)
1  (5, 7, 5, 3)
1  (6, 8, 1, 0)
3  (7, 8, 3, 2)
```

Then your can rename index and columns

Comment: Yes that's it ! Thank you very much for your solution ! Btw, I don't know who -1 my question, but I don't diserve it..

Comment: This is amazing! was stuck in the exact same situation and this save my life! It's sooo much faster than value_counts()!

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do a simple `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']).size()

val1  val2  val3  val4
0     2     5     7       1
1     4     5     4       2
5     7     5     3       1
6     8     1     0       1
7     8     3     2       3
```

And if you must have them as tuples:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']).size(), index=s.index.to_native_types(), columns=['count']).reset_index()

          index  count
0  (0, 2, 5, 7)      1
1  (1, 4, 5, 4)      2
2  (5, 7, 5, 3)      1
3  (6, 8, 1, 0)      1
4  (7, 8, 3, 2)      3
```

Comment: didn't know about `to_native_types`. What's the purpose of this function?

Comment: My understanding is that it is similar to `tolist()` but also allows to control how to represent `NaN`s. So essentially `to_native_types` can be replaced with `tolist` in the above code. And `s` is the `groupby(...).size()` Series.

Answer (score 0):

In python Use [`Collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

s = """7    8    3    2
1    4    5    4
5    7    5    3
7    8    3    2
6    8    1    0
0    2    5    7
1    4    5    4
7    8    3    2"""

In [74]: Counter(s.translate(None, ' ').split())
Out[74]: Counter({'7832': 3, '1454': 2, '5753': 1, '0257': 1, '6810': 1})
```

`str.translate()` with `None` will give you string of nombers by removing all spaces then `str.split()` will split and provide individual string in a `list`.

```
In [73]: s.translate(None, ' ').split()
Out[73]: ['7832', '1454', '5753', '7832', '6810', '0257', '1454', '7832']
```

Comment: @user3478208 check the solution.

Comment: Is your S a DataFrame?

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I don't really understand what kind of s you have.

Comment: @user3478208 i don't know about panda's framework but s is a string and in pythonic way you can solve it like this.

Comment: I am sorry, I said in the question It was a pandas DataFrame. Thank you for your time anyway.